# How to reduce the complexity of Longest repeated sequesnce

Tags: python, algorithm

Last week, I had an interview with Amazon.
The interviewer asked the a question to findout longest repeated substring in `banana`
If we will look into the string `banana`, we will see `ana` (repeated 2 times) is an overlapped repeated string.
I could able to reach the solution but my final output was wrong. 
Anyways, he said with this approach the complexity is `O(n^2)`, which is right.
After the interview I corrected my code now it is giving correct output. But I have searched all over internet how to reduce the complexity. I can not able to find it. Could you please help me reducing the complexity or any reference whcih I can follow to reduce the complexity.

```
mystring = "banana"
temp = ""
arr = {}
for i in range(len(mystring)):
    for j in range(i, len(mystring)):
        temp += mystring[j]
        try:
            arr[temp] += 1
        except:
            arr[temp] = 1
    temp = ""
temp = 0
finalstr = ""
for k, v in arr.iteritems():
    if len(k) > 1:
        if temp < v and len(finalstr) < len(k):
            temp = v
            finalstr = k
print finalstr
```

Comment: Not really that much helpful, however this can be done in O(n) time: Build a suffix tree (O(n) time and space, Ukkonen's algorithm) and find the deepest branching node (a simply visit of the tree). Unfortunately the Ukkonen's algorithm isn't a trivial algorithm...

Comment: By the way: if I were an amazon intreviewer I would have been much more trouble about you using a bare `except:` instead of the O(N^2) complexity... **Always** specify the kind of exception you want to catch, even `except Exception:` is better than just `except:` because at least it still allows you to interrupt the program using Ctrl+C etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I could have used `if temp in arr` and `else` but that again increases complexity to another O(n)

Comment: Actually given that `arr` is a dictionary `temp in arr` takes O(1) time, not O(n). Also I mean that using `except KeyError:` is much better than usign `except:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved in *linear time* O(N) by using [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). A suffix tree is a tree that contains all suffices of a given text. Moreover they take time and space O(N) to build.

The tree has edges labelled with substrings of the text. The wikipedia page handily provides the suffix tree for the word `banana`:

[image: Image of the suffix tree for the word banana]

If you start at the root and go down, reading the edges you'll find all possible suffices of `banana`.

**Note**: if you think about it the sum of lengths of all suffices is `1+2+3+...+N = N*(N-1)/2=O(N^2)`! The trick is that you don't actually label the edges with the strings. You have your text `T` as a string, and you identify its substrings using two indices `i` and `j`, so when you want to read the label of an edge you go to index `i` and read up to `j`.

Now the idea is that if a string is repeated inside a text, as `ana` in `banana` then you have that that string is the prefix of two different suffices:

```
banana
 | |
 +-+--  prefix of suffix: anana
   |--  prefix of suffix: ana
```

so we start from the root of the suffix tree, we read `a` and we go to the left, then we read `NA` and we go to the right. As you can see the node where we ended up has two children:

- Going to the left we read `$`, i.e. end-of-string which means we have read the suffix `ana`
- Going to the right we read `na$`, which means we have read the suffix `anana`.

**Note:** this holds for *any* repeated substring. So every repeated substring corresponds to a branching node.

Hence the labels from the root to the *deepest* branching node will always form the *longest* repeated subsequence.
To find this node you can just do a single visit of the tree.

To build a suffix tree the most known algorithm is due to Ukkonnen, which you may find [described in this article](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf). The algorithm itself is non-trivial.

---

I want also to add some comments regarding your solution.

First of all: you should **never** use a bare `except:` without specifying the type of exception you want to catch. Your current code, for example, might prevent the user from interrupting it using Ctrl+C because the `except:` would catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.
In future interviews remember to use `except ExceptionType` with the most specific exception type you need (in this case `except KeyError:`).

Secondly, the `collections` module provides a `Counter` class that is written for exactly the purpose of counting things, so you could rewrite your code as simply as:

```
from collections import Counter

length = len(mystring)
counts = Counter(mystring[i:j] for i in range(length) for j in range(i, length))

print(max(counts, key=lambda x: (counts[x] >= 2, len(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you grow the String temp in the order "b"-"ba"-..., then "a"-"an"-... so you are testing from the smallest to the largest parts.

Do you have the possibility to avoid the worst case scenario systematically ?

For exemple by dividing you string starting by 2 to K, K being the first integer where (len(string)/2) - 1 = K (K+1 if odd). In case of odd length string association should be done.

For exemple abcdedekgb len(abcdedekgb)=10 K=4

```
=> 10/2 = 5 ::  abcde|dekgb,

=> 10/3 =~ (3+1) :: abcd|abc|bcd|bcde|cde|cded|ded|dede|ede|edek|dek|dekg|ekg|ekgb|kgb.

=>10/4 =~ (2+1) :: ....
```

Algorithm for segmentation of not integer is (for case of 10/3) :
len(sequence) = 3+1 and len(sequence) = 3;
next position is +1;

At each iteration test is there exist any repetition, if not k = k+1 until k = K.

If the word is large enough this will avoid the worst case scenario easily